# HTML Add value in textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add value in text box. A text box is already created with default value equal 10, then a button use a function to adding
new text box with limit 4. therefore, i want to add value continuously
from text box 1 to text box 4

Example:

Text box 1 value = 10

Text box 2 value = 20

Text box 3 value = 30

Text box 4 value = 40

How can i do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Adding New Line Item Function
    var i = 1;
    function AddNew(){
        if (i <=3){ //if you don't want limit, you remove IF condition
            i++;
            var div= document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="lineitem_'+i+'" maxlength="2" size="2"><input type="button" onclick="removeKid(this)" value="-">';
            document.getElementById('addingitem').appendChild(div);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add value continuously from text box 1 to text box 4 ,so [`while`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp) loop is more better here

```
 var i = 1;
    function AddNew(){
        while(i < 4 ){
            i++;
            var div = document.getElementById("addingitem");
            div.innerHTML += '<br>Text box '+i+' <input type="text" name="lineitem_'+i+'" maxlength="2" size="2" value="'+i*10+'"><input type="button" onclick="removeKid(this)" value="-">';            
        }
    }
```

Comment: next step i use a function to remove textbox; but value does show consequence if i remove middle of text box: function removeKid(div){
  document.getElementById('addingitem').removeChild(div.parentNode);
  i--;
 }                                                                                                                               Text box 1  value=10, Text box 2 value=20, Text box 3 value=30, then i remove Text box 2, the value of Text Box 3 doesn't change to 20 it keep 30. i add one more text box but value is 30. it's double value of Text Box 3 and new Text Box.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="textboxes">
    Text box 1 <input type="text" value="10" />
</div>

<button onclick="AddNew()" >Add</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Adding New Line Item Function
    var i = 1;
    function AddNew(){
    var div= document.getElementById('textboxes');  
        if (i <4){ 
            i++;            
           div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML+'<br>Text box '+i+' <input type="text" value="'+i*10+'" />';

        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will add 5 boxes in total. Also try to use `Element.insertAdjacentHTML` for such "append" stuff.

Comment: modified to 4 boxes. why we have to use Element.insertAdjacentHTML? can you please explain?