# Add a character to separate results in a form output only when the text box has text

Tags: javascript, html, string, forms, concatenation

I made a form that renders text after the user fills up the text boxes. I want to add an underscore between words but only when a text box is filled with text.

Box1: One

Box2: *(empty)*

Box3: Three

Current Result: One__Three *(notice the double underscore)*

**Desired result: One_Three.**

```
    <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="totalamount.value = client.value + '_' + campaign.value + '_' + spotname.value + '_' + market.value">
                
            <ul >
            <li id="li_1" >
                <div>Client:<input name="client" id="client" type="text" maxlength="100" value="" /></div></li>
            <li id="li_2" >
                <div>Campaign:<input name="campaign" id="campaign" type="text" value="" /></div></li>
            <li id="li_3" >
                <div>Spot Name:<input name="spotname" id="spotname" type="text" value="" /></div></li>
            <li id="li_4" >
                <div>Market:<input list="market" name="market" />
                    <datalist id="market">
                        <option value="HM" >
                        <option value="OLV" >
                        <option value="SM_Vertical" >
                        <option value="SM_Square" >
                        <option value="GM" >
                        <option value="InternalUse" >
                        <option value="Country?" >
                    </datalist>
                </div></li>
            <li id="li_5" align="center" style="font-weight:bolder; background-color: #F5F5F5; padding:10px">
                <output name="totalamount" id="totalamount" for="filename"></output>
                </li>
```

I know the `_` is adding the underscore, but I don't know how to add it to a value so it only shows in the result box when there is text in the corresponding text box.

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

Comment: You have to it with JavaScript. Do some search with JavaScript and it will do it. Take a look at this link and search more links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581747/html-add-value-in-textbox

Comment: @Hamed_gibago OP has JavaScript in the form of on event attribute. Note the `onsubmit` and `oninput` on `<form>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following on event attributes to the `<form>`:

```
onkeyup
onkeydown
onchange
```

Asign the following expression to each of the attributes previously listed:

```
 totalamount.value = totalamount.value.replace(/_{2,}/, '_')
```

So now every keystroke will be covered from 2 to 3 times as well as anytime focus is lost. On "keyup", "keydown", and "change" events, the value of `totalamount` will be searched for a pattern consisting of two or more consecutive occurance of an underscore -- any match will be replaced by a single underscore.

Also the `[for]` attribute has been corrected to the `#id`s of the four `<input>`s: `"client campaign spotname market"`. Whether it makes a difference in this situation IDK, but I didn't see any `"filename"` anyhow.

```css
:root {
  font: 1ch/1.5 'Segoe UI';
}

body {
  font-size: 3ch;
}

label,
output,
input {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit
}

label {
  width: 10ch
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="totalamount.value = client.value + '_' + campaign.value + '_' + spotname.value + '_' + market.value" onkeyup="totalamount.value = totalamount.value.replace(/_{2,}/, '_')" onkeydown="totalamount.value = totalamount.value.replace(/_{2,}/, '_')"
  onchange="totalamount.value = totalamount.value.replace(/_{2,}/, '_')">

  <label for='client'>
  Client: </label>
  <input name="client" id="client" type="text" maxlength="100" value="">
  <br>
  <label for='campaign'>
  Campaign: </label>
  <input name="campaign" id="campaign" type="text" value="">
  <br>
  <label for='spotname'>
  Spot Name: </label>
  <input name="spotname" id="spotname" type="text" value="">
  <br>
  <label for='market'>
  Market: </label>
  <input list="market" name="market">
  <datalist id="market">
    <option value="HM">
    <option value="OLV">
    <option value="SM_Vertical">
    <option value="SM_Square">
    <option value="GM">
    <option value="InternalUse">
    <option value="Country?" >
  </datalist>
  <br>
  <label for='totalamount'>Total Amount: </label>
  <output name="totalamount" id="totalamount" for="client campaign spotname market"></output>
</form>
```

A different version based on OPs comments below.

```css
:root {
  font: 1ch/1.5 'Segoe UI';
}

body {
  font-size: 3ch;
}

label,
output,
input {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit
}

label {
  width: 10ch
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="final.value = client.value + campaign.value + tag.value + market.value + version.value" onchange="final.value = client.value + campaign.value + tag.value + market.value + version.value">

  <label for='client'>
  Client: </label>
  <input name="client" id="client" onchange="this.value = this.value.length < 1 || this.value === '_' ? '' : '_'+this.value" type="text" maxlength="100" value="">
  <br>
  <label for='campaign'>
  Campaign: </label>
  <input name="campaign" id="campaign" onchange="this.value = this.value.length < 1 || this.value === '_' ? '' : '_'+this.value" type="text" value="">
  <br>
  <label for='tag'>
  Tag: </label>
  <input name="tag" id="tag" onchange="this.value = this.value.length < 1 || this.value === '_' ? '' : '_'+this.value" type="text" value="">
  <br>
  <label for='market'>
  Market: </label>
  <input list="market" name="market" onchange="this.value = this.value.length < 1 || this.value === '_' ? '' : '_'+this.value">
  <datalist id="market">
    <option value="HM">
    <option value="OLV">
    <option value="SM_Vertical">
    <option value="SM_Square">
    <option value="GM">
    <option value="InternalUse">
    <option value="Country?" >
  </datalist>
  <br>
  <label for='version'>
  Version: </label>
  <input name="version" id="version" onchange="this.value = this.value.length < 1 || this.value === '_v' ? '' : '_v'+this.value" type="text" value="">
  <br>
  <label for='final'>Final: </label>
  <output name="final" id="final" for="client campaign tag market version"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: Following up on this, do you think is possible to add characters before the text instead of deleting duplicated underscores? I want to add a new text box asking for version number, the user should type a number but the rendered filename should display: _v(number written by user).

Comment: I don't believe it's possible using on event attributes unless you define the callback functions -- which means separating the JavaScript from the HTML (strongly recommended).... (cont.)

Comment: ...(cont) The use of the [on event attribute](https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events#html-attribute) is generally discouraged in favor of [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) (recommended) and to some extent [on event properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#using_onevent_properties). Using either one of the latter allows more flexibility and control, but most importantly they allow you to use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

Comment: The reason why duplicated underscores are deleted is because they are generated by each input everytime a keystroke happens on any input. The 'input', 'keydown' events do not detect backspace key and 'keyup' is used if 'change' hasn't happened yet. The pattern can be adapted to the event handler in the example above.

Comment: @canelson See second example, your request is possible I stand corrected.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This is just a template I want to use at work to create standardized filenames (I'm a video editor). I already added all the CSS to the HTML so I can have just one file in my desktop and use it to create filenames. Again, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I tried the second example but it's giving me some errors. I'll stay with the first one that is working fine except for the _v for versions. Thanks a lot! I wouldn't find a solution to this issue by myself.